# socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, ftp

I would like to use python to transfer files between two computers.
I use ftplib module in client side and pyftpdlib on sever side. However, I got error "socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it". My code is below:

Client side code:

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP("sever_ip")
ftp.login("username", "password")
ftp.retrlines("LIST")
```

Server side code:

```
from pyftpdlib import servers, handlers
address = ('', 21)  
server = servers.FTPServer(address, handlers.FTPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

I run the server side code and get:

```
[I 15-05-28 11:14:41] >>> starting FTP server on :::21, pid=8296 <<<
[I 15-05-28 11:14:41] poller: <class 'pyftpdlib.ioloop.Select'>
[I 15-05-28 11:14:41] masquerade (NAT) address: None
[I 15-05-28 11:14:41] passive ports: None
```

I run the client side code and get:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

What settings do I need to change or examine on the target computer (server) to make it accept connections? (My server is Windows Sever 2012R2 and my client is Windows 8)

Updates:
I turned on the firewall of my server and I rerun my client request. Now I got a different error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a per
iod of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: So is the remote server configured to accept connections from you on port 21? Because you're connecting and it says: "NO!!"

Comment: That would be a good topic for a completely different SO question than what you have written, which probably does not belong on the Python tag. Maybe instead, though, you could just edit that into your current question and expand your tags.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will modify it.

Comment: And thank you for taking the advice so kindly! I tried a little edit and a tag suggestion, but it's a bit out of my field. We need to get better eyes on this! Oh and also -- post what version of Windows at least the server but probably also the client is running.

Comment: I would like to know when you say "Because you're connecting and it says: "NO!!" ", do you mean i needs to get passive ports enabled?